# "The Blessed One", is it bad translation?

Tags: theravada, sutras, buddha, translation, english

I found "The Blessed One" in English translation of Suttas. Because in Buddhism blessing is not legit/proper word to use to anyone, especially Buddha need not to be blessed, is it loosely translated or in purpose? I didn't see any part of Sutta that one can be blessed or a meaning that blessing can be done so far. What should be proper translation of "The Blessed One" in Sutta if it is bad translation?

Answer (score 7):

A couple of dictionary translations:

- > [Bhagavā](http://www.buddha-vacana.org/gloss.html#bhagava): venerable, fortunate, blessed, sublime. Generally designates the Buddha.
- > [Bhagavant](http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.2:1:3436.pali) (adj. n.) [cp. Vedic bhagavant, fr. bhaga] fortunate, illustrious, sublime, as Ep. and title "Lord." Thus applied to the Buddha (amhākaŋ Bh.) and his predecessors. Occurs with extreme frequency; of fanciful exegetic explns of the term & its meaning we mention e. g. those at Nd1 142=Nd2 466; Vism 210 sq.; DA i.33 sq. Usual trs. Blessed One, Exalted One.

Also, perhaps as an etymology:

- > [Bhaga](http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.2:1:3433.pali) [Vedic bhaga, bhaj, see bhagavant etc.] luck, lot, fortune, only in cpd. dub˚ (adj.) unhappy, unpleasant, uncomfortable It 90; DA i.96 (˚karaṇa). -- bhaga (in verse "bhagehi ca vibhattavā" in exegesis of word "Bhagava") at DA i.34 read bhava, as read at id. p. Vism 210.

---

Here are some [definitions of "blessed" from an American dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blessed) (perhaps Protestant culture):

> Simple Definition of blessed
>   : having a sacred nature : connected with God
>   : very welcome, pleasant, or appreciated
>
> Full Definition of blessed
>
> 1. a :  held in reverence :  venerated 
>      b :  honored in worship :  hallowed 
>      c :  beatific
> 2. :  of or enjoying happiness; specifically :  enjoying the bliss of heaven —used as a title for a beatified person
> 3. :  bringing pleasure, contentment, or good fortune

I think you might see that many of these definitions are suitable.

You're right that it's probably not blessed in a Catholic sense, i.e. sanctified via the agency of a priest.

Answer (score 5):

The word is '[bhagava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhagavan#Etymology_and_meaning)', from '[bhaga](http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/search3advanced?dbname=pali&query=bhagava&matchtype=exact&display=utf8)'.

You may prefer 'Fortunate One' if you believe 'blessings' can only be given by a person or a god.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah; in the original text of The Bible (when Jesus is giving The Beatitudes, saying "Blessed are the 'this' & Blessed are the 'that"), the word they translated "Blessed" actually means something more like 'deliriously, abundantly joyfully-happy.'

Answer (score 0):

Well the term is translated as The World Honored One in Chinese

Comment: [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhahood#Ten_characteristics_of_a_Buddha), `The tenth epithet is sometimes listed as "The World Honored Enlightened One" (Skt. Buddha-Lokanatha) or "The Blessed Enlightened One" (Skt. Buddha-Bhagavan).` "World Honored" is presumably *Lokanatha* rather than *Bhagavan*; I'm don't know why they're listed together. The root *Loka* means "world" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The Chinese name for "Buddha" is ”世尊", which means “The Respected One”。 “One” is with relation to the "法界"， or "The Dharma Realm" in English or scientifically speaking， “The Universe”